# Classes and property use in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am learning Angular2 on https://angular.io/. While following the tutorial I end up writing the following code

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
 selector: 'app-root',
 templateUrl: './app.component.html',
 styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})
export class AppComponent {
 title = 'Tour of Heroes';
 hero: Hero = {
   id: 1,
   name: 'windstorm'
 };
}

export class Hero {
 id: number;
 name: string;
}
```

Here My question is in class Hero and object hero in class AppComponent ":" is used to declare and assign the values to properties but why "=" is used to assign values of title property.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because in the title you are assigning a value. This is plain javascript:

```
title = 'Tour of Heroes';
```

While the hero, you are saying that, your hero property has a type of `Hero` and you are also assigning it a new value, that's typescript:

```
hero: Hero = {
   id: 1,
   name: 'windstorm'
 };
```

So you could do something similar to your title, although it's redundant:

```
 title:string = 'Tour of Heroes';
```

Why it's redundant? because title is a primitive type, when you assign a string to it, typescript already knows that your title variable is a string type;

Answer (score 1):

The statement `hero: Hero` is a Typescript expression that lets Typescript know that the property `hero` will be using the `Hero` Typescript interface.

Then using the `=` the actual vaue is assigned to the property.

The reason this was left out for `title` is that you are passing it a simple string and Typescript infers that the type of the `title` variable has to be `string`. So you don't have to define the type of the `title` specifically.

Answer (score 1):

`id: number;` declares a property id, of **type** number.

`title = 'Tour of Heroes';` declares a property title, and initializes it with the **value** 'Tour of Heroes'. Its type, string, is inferred by the TypeScript compiler. But it's in fact equivalent to

```
title: string = 'Tour of Heroes';
```

This is somewhat basic TypeScript syntax. [Learn the language](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/tutorial.html).

Answer (score 1):

In javascript

An equal sign, **=**, is used to assign variables:

```
let title = 'Hello';
```

And a colon, **:**, (in this case) is used to separate the *key* from its *value* in a `javascript object`:

```
let hero: Hero = {
   id: 1,
   name: 'windstorm'
 };
```

The first colon in the example above though, is a *typescript* notation for specifying a *type* for the hero variable.

Answer (score 1):

```
title = 'Tour of Heroes';
```

Here, you are saying that property `title` of class `AppComponent` has this value `'Tour of Heroes'`.
You could have specified like this:

```
title: string = 'Tour of Heroes';
```

But by assigning a value of type: `string`, TypeScript understands that `title` is already type `string`, without having to specify it.

Instead, here:

```
  hero: Hero = {
   id: 1,
   name: 'windstorm'
 };
```

You are saying that property `hero` of class `AppComponent` is type `Hero` and has this value:

```
{id: 1, name: 'windstorm'}
```

So with **:** you declare the type of the property. With **=** you are assigning it's value.

Answer (score 0):

```
hero: Hero = {
   id: 1,
   name: 'windstorm'
 };
```

In this case, `Hero`is the class of hero. Then (with the "=" ) you're assigning the JS Object `{ id: 1, name: 'windstorm'};` to your `hero`variable.

```
title = 'Tour of Heroes';
```

Here you're just assigning the value to a variable, without stating its type.

```
title : string = 'Tour of Heroes';
```

or even

```
title : any = 'Tour of Heroes';
```